# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 - library not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I have a bit of a problem building my project. I'm getting the bellow error for some reason since last week and cannot get rid of it.

```
Ld /Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartPic-elnbgmemojraijcotdlcskagbibq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SmartPic.app/SmartPic normal armv7
    cd "/Users/Nathan/Documents/Xcode Projects/SmartPic"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
-L/Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartPic-elnbgmemojraijcotdlcskagbibq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
-F/Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartPic-elnbgmemojraijcotdlcskagbibq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartPic-elnbgmemojraijcotdlcskagbibq/Build/Intermediates/SmartPic.build/Debug-iphoneos/SmartPic.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SmartPic.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework MessageUI -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework AudioToolbox -lDMReader -o /Users/Nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartPic-elnbgmemojraijcotdlcskagbibq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SmartPic.app/SmartPic

ld: library not found for -lDMReader
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I searched for information about the erorr, as, at one point, I had 6 other similar ones and the answer was to delete Library Search Paths in the Build Settings and that got rid of all but this last one. It was all fine until I imported some extra frameworks and classes. So not sure really what's caused it and how I can fix it.

I'm still fairly new to app development, so please try not to get *too* technical.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this by changing Library Search Paths in Build Settings to

> ./Classes "$(SRCROOT)/Classes"

Just in case anyone else finds this and wants to give it a try.

EDIT:
Just to add, I had this same problem again just now actually. And the reason it happened for me is because I changed the folder name that sits with the .xcodeproj file. So In a folder on my mac I had a directory called `App Name` and file called `App Name.xcodeproj`. I changed the directory App Name to something different and despite updating the build settings in xcode, still had the same problem. What I had to do was

- Right Click `App Name.xcodeproj`
- Click `Show Package Contents`
- Open `project.pbxproj`
- Then cmd + f (search) and enter `App Name`, I think there were just two places and they were 1/3 of the way down the page, called `name` and immediately below, `path`. Change them to the new directory name, save and reopen your project and all should be well.