# 'Framework not found AudioUnit' when trying to build Audiobus iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, clang, audiounit

I am experimenting with [Cycling 74's Gen](http://cycling74.com/products/gen/) and attempting to build the [Audiobus iOS Project](http://cycling74.com/wiki/index.php?title=Gen_Code_Export_iOS) in Xcode 5.1.1.  The project needs the [Audiobus](https://github.com/eumlab/Audiobus/blob/master/Audiobus.podspec) SDK 1 which I was able to access checking out an earlier version since the current version is 2.1.3.  It also needs the [The Amazing Audio Engine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/).

I got up to Step 9 'Build the Xcode project for the device' in the project instructions but received many Mach-O Linker Errors when building:

[image: Mach-O Linker Errors]

I read that these errors are almost always related to Frameworks (built in iOS frameworks) not included in the project so I took a look at the project imports and found a couple of references to `#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>`.  I then added the `AudioUnit.framework` and sure enough, the majority of the errors went away.

I was left with one error:

```
Ld /Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Intermediates/GenFilter.build/Debug-iphoneos/GenFilter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GenFilter normal armv7
cd /Users/davechambers/Desktop/Max6_Gen_Demo_Projects_iOS_and_VST/iOS/iOSGenFilter
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/davechambers/Desktop/Max6_Gen_Demo_Projects_iOS_and_VST/iOS/iOSGenFilter -F/Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Intermediates/GenFilter.build/Debug-iphoneos/GenFilter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GenFilter.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -framework AudioUnit -framework CoreAudio -lTheAmazingAudioEngine -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework AudioToolbox -framework Accelerate -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lAudiobus -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Intermediates/GenFilter.build/Debug-iphoneos/GenFilter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GenFilter_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/davechambers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GenFilter-btaipzocrdohxhbhznstjchlytad/Build/Intermediates/GenFilter.build/Debug-iphoneos/GenFilter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/GenFilter

ld: framework not found AudioUnit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my problem and I have been unable to get rid of this last error.  Contrary to suggestion in the following SO answers, removing AudioUnit.framework and adding CoreAudio.framework didn't help but brought back all the Mach-O Linker Errors shown above:

[audiounit-framework-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464588/audiounit-framework-not-found)

[framework-not-found-audiounit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756212/framework-not-found-audiounit)

The following posts didn't help me either:

[ld-framework-not-found-audiounit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120878/ld-framework-not-found-audiounit)

[clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-library-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769744/clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-library-not-found?rq=1)

I have uploaded the project to [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3-JRETAp68mZDRJWUg0V0F0WnM/edit?pli=1). If anybody has the time to take a look and see where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**The Quick Answer:** 
Remove ALL frameworks and comment out references to said frameworks, then add in each framework that will be depended upon. I did a build following this part to ensure I was still error free, although I had to use AudioToolbox in place of AudioUnit. Lastly, add in your dependent framework and build.

Comment: Answers should short and to-the-point, there is no need for story telling.

Comment: Thanks Adam. On vacation at the moment but will check this out next week.  Cheers